# How to get a selected item from a ListPreference

Tags: java, android

Im working on a little notepad for a card game and I want to be able to choose the amount of players via a settings activity.
I managed to create a preference screen with a ListPreference where the amount of players can be selected.
How can I get and refer to this selection in my MainActivity.class so I can do something like this:

```
if(amountPlayers < 3){
        editText3main.setKeyListener(null);
        editText4main.setKeyListener(null);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ListPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) will store a string into the SharedPreferences. To retrieve it, use

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
String defaultValue = "-1"; // assign some meaningful default value
int amountPlayers = Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("NUM_OF_PLAYERS_PREF_KEY", defaultValue));
```

More on this in android [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference).

Comment: Doing it like this, changing the amount of players in the settings doesnt affect the variable "amountPlayers" somehow...changing the defaultValue works though, I do find the pref key in the preferencescreen under ListPreference, right?

Comment: It won't affect amountPlayers variable unless you assign newly chosen value to the amountPlayers variable. See last line of the code I've posted.

Comment: you mean like this?: <code>int amountPlayers = settings.getInt("list_preference_1", defaultValue); </code>

Comment: Thats my problem, it doesnt change by user input. It only takes the defaulValue from line 2 regardless how many players are selected

Comment: Do you store ListPreference values in <string-array> ?

Comment: I forgot, that ListPreference stores values as strings, and in my example I've tried to get integers. My mistake. I've edited my answer, try the updated solution.

Comment: Where should I put that code? In my MainActivity.class the getActivity() doesnt work and in my Fragment class where its supposed to be the getString method doesnt work...puting it in my mainactivity class and swapping it with "this" the same problem as earlier comes up

Comment: It depends where the logic you've posted is located. If it is in activity, in your case MainActivity, then use getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) without getActivity(). If the logic is located in the fragment, then yout must use getActivity() in order to get activity your fragment is attached to.

Comment: hmm *scratching head*  It still looks like only the variable "defaultValue" is affecting the variable "amountPlayers"...Is there another way to access the listpreference?

Comment: Replace the first line of my example with SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) if executed from MainActivity or  SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()) if executed from fragment. Let me know if it works.